# Google Sheet scripts - Authorization process broken - Error 401: disabled-client

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that I have used for many years which is attached to a Responses Sheet for a Google Form.  Every time a submission is made to the Form the script will email out the entry from the Responses Sheet.  Recently, Google deleted my authorization data forcing me to re-authorize the script.  I went into my Responses Sheet and ran the script causing the Authorization prompt to display.  I pressed Review Permissions.  Normally, this would take me to the sign in for my account but instead I am getting an Authorization Error:  Error 401:  disabled_client

I have tried to search for a result to this problem and have not found one. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Google Chrome is up to date:
Version 88.0.4324.150 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63371251/authorizing-a-script-for-a-google-spreadsheet-gives-me-error-401-deleted-client

Comment: @Cooper Your first link talks about signing into a web app which is not what I'm doing. This is a basic Google Sheet.  The second link accurately describes the problem but didn't really provide a solution.  I went to Resources > Cloud Platform project then clicked on my project.  I got a message saying the project was shutdown and scheduled to be deleted.  Which is slowly taking me outside my technical skill and beyond my non-admin privileges.  Does any of this make sense?

Comment: Seeing as you are unable to manage GCP projects, you will need to create a fresh project and copy your code over to that one. Ideally I would start afresh with new documents too. Is it possible that your admin is performing a cleanup?

Comment: @iansedano The more I look into this, the more I feel I will have to start from scratch which is horrible because this problem exists in more than one Sheet.  I have contacted my IT and they have said no changes were made to App Script or the GCP (nor do they really have anyone who can support me in this journey).  As a basic user, there is no reason for me to be managing the GCP projects.

Comment: I would suggest a couple things. Look into [Libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries) so that its easier to distribute your script in future, and also watch this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwtw6fSARek  - Its not too much work to restore GCP projects and this might save you the work of copying the script, though I would suggest using libraries or add-ons to distribute your work, because its a matter of time before something else like this happens!

Answer (score 1):

Posting this for reference in case of future users:

#### It appears that your linked GCP project is being deleted

As you have mentioned, your Apps Script project has been scheduled to be deleted and this is interfering with your authorization process.

You can read more about Apps Script and GCP projects here:

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects

Usually Apps Script projects are attached to a "deafault GCP project" that is not visible via `console.developers.google.com` - *however* as may be your case, for older projects (previous to 2018/19) this project may be visible.

#### Cancel deletion of your GCP Project

This video has step by step instructions on how to do this:

> https://youtube.com/watch?v=bwtw6fSARek

Which essentially takes you to the list of active projects, where at the bottom you can see the projects pending to be deleted. In the list of projects to be deleted, you can find the option to "restore" them.

#### Alternatively, just create a new project

If you don't want to manage GCP projects and take advantage of the new "default" project that is attached to new scripts, then you will have to start a new Apps Script project and move everything over, as there is no way to go back to the default GCP project, once the Apps Script is linked to it. That is, once a GCP project is visibly linked to the Apps Script project, you can't go back to the default.

Comment: I appreciate all of your help.  I honestly don't see the reason for me to be in the GCP project space.  I'm just an education teacher trying to manage a simple script.  I re-created everything and started over.  My only lingering question is why this happened in the first place if my organization made no changes? (the form was created in 2015)

Comment: I wish I knew! Sometimes the unexpected happens I am afraid. Maybe there is a auto-cleanup policy at the admin level. Perhaps you could ask your admin to get in touch with Workspace support to understand what the issue was. With the move to the new IDE and Apps Script structure, its possible that some wires were crossed...